# Using transactions during reads using Entity Framework 6+

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

In our dev team we have an interesting discussion regarding opening transactions during reads in Entity Framework.

Case is this: we have unit of work in MVC app which spans action methods - simple open EF transaction before executing action and commits after no error appears during execution. This is fine and maybe some of you use an UoW pattern with EF in that way.

Interesting part is what about actions that performs only reads (no modification of any entity for example get by id). Should transaction be opened also for reads? What would be the difference in approach when we don't open transaction and during read there is active transaction on same table we read data not using tran? Suppose that we have set default transaction isolation level to read committed.

I was pro opening transaction which keeps reads consistent but there are things against like transactions slowdown reads (which is true but I don't know how much).

What are your thoughts? I know that some of u will answer as old architects saying "it depends" but I need strong arguments not hate :)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server at READ COMMITTED isolation there is no difference between a SELECT inside a transaction and one outside a transaction.

With legacy READ COMMITTED the S locks are released at the end of each query even in a transaction.

With READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT (which is the default for EF Code First) there are no S locks taken, and row versions provide only a statement-level point-in-time view of the database.

At SNAPSHOT isolation, the whole transaction would see the database at a single point-in-time, still with no locking.

Comment: What is difference in performance opening transaction and not opening transaction?

Comment: If only SELECT queries for SQL Server at READ COMMITTED, no difference in performance.  No difference in locking.  No difference in results.